# Custom picklist in vf page by using java script

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have one picklist, values with city names.and i have 3 text fields .
if i select one value from picklist,seleted value(item value) should be populate in the 1st text field.in 2nd text field ---item label should be populate,in 3rd field both itemlabel and itemvalue should be populate. Can this can be achieved by javascript?

```
<apex:page id="page" controller="PicklistExam">
    <apex:form  id="fm">
        <apex:outputLabel value="CITIES " onclick=""  id=""/>
        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!Selected}">
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="-NONE-" itemvalue="none"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="HYDERABAD" itemvalue="TS"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="PUNE" itemvalue="MR"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="BENGALURU" itemvalue="KA" />
        </apex:selectList> <br/>
        <apex:inputText /> <br/>
        <apex:inputText /> <br/>
        <apex:inputText /> <br/>
        <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!show}"/> 
        {!result}
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) to keep the code simple:

```
<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!Selected}" styleClass="selectMarker">
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="-NONE-" itemvalue="none"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="HYDERABAD" itemvalue="TS"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="PUNE" itemvalue="MR"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemLabel="BENGALURU" itemvalue="KA" />
</apex:selectList> <br/>
<apex:inputText styleClass="text1Marker" /> <br/>
<apex:inputText styleClass="text2Marker"/> <br/>
<apex:inputText styleClass="text2Marker" /> <br/>


<!-- Add this just before the end of the oage -->
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'></script>
<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.selectMarker').change(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            var label = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            $('.text1Marker').val(value);
            $('.text2Marker').val(label);
            $('.text3Marker').val(label + ' ' + value);
        });
    });
})(jQuery.noConflict());
</script>
```

When the page has loaded (the DOM is `ready`), a `change` listener is added to the element that has the class `selectMarker`. So when that element changes, the function extracts the value and label and then sets those as the values of the 3 input fields.

(I haven't run this so there may be mistakes in it.)